# Cucumber report does not get updated after Parallel execution of feature files in Protractor+Typescript framework

Tags: typescript, parallel-processing, protractor, cucumber

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr0aB.jpg)Below is my config.ts file. I have done below configuration to suffice parallel execution of feature files.

However after execution the cucumber report fails to get updated and always shows last execution result only.

Also for every feature it executes it generates corresponding json files like this hence multiple json files are getting generated, which not sure is causing this problem or not.

What am I missing here which rectifies this issue can anyone help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm8tC.jpg)
Attaching

1. screenshot of multiple json files generated

```
    import { Config } from 'protractor';
    //var reporter = require('cucumber-html-reporter');
    import * as reporter from 'cucumber-html-reporter';
    import options from 'cucumber-html-reporter';
    
    export let config: Config = {
        seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
        //seleniumAddress:'http://10.157.150.114:4444/wd/hub',
        framework:'custom',
        // directConnect:true,
        frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    
        capabilities: {
         browserName: 'chrome',
         acceptInsecureCerts : true,
         shardTestFiles:true,
         maxInstances:2,
         chromeOptions: {
          args: [ "--disable-site-isolation-trials" ]
        }
    
        },
    
        suites:{
          bau:'../FeatureFiles/BAU/**/*.feature',
          santoriniTest:'../FeatureFiles/Santorini/**/*.feature',
          installmentconfig:'../FeatureFiles/BAU/InstallmentConfig/*.feature',
          panlist:'../FeatureFiles/BAU/Panlist.feature',
          merchantlist:'../FeatureFiles/BAU/Merchantlist.feature',
          subaccount:'../FeatureFiles/Maintenance/subaccountrange.feature',
          all:'../FeatureFiles/**/*.feature',
          notification:'../FeatureFiles/notificationauto.feature'
        },
    
        //specs: ['../FeatureFiles/Santorini/**/EtaToEtgOfferCreation.feature'],
        specs: ['../FeatureFiles/Santorini/ETAETGOfferCreation/TC2765844.feature','../FeatureFiles/Santorini/SPPSPSOfferCreation/TC2796855.feature'],
        //SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER:false,
        rootElement: '[ng-app]',
        cucumberOpts: {
    
         //tags:"@help",
         //tags:"@Regression",
         //tags:"@Smoke",
    
          format:'json:./cucumberreport.json',
    
            require: [
              './StepDefinitions/**/*.js' // accepts a glob
            ]
          },
          onComplete : () => {
            var options = {
              theme: 'bootstrap',
              jsonFile: './cucumberreport.*.json',
              output: 'TestExecutinReport/cucumber_report.html',
              reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
              launchReport: true,
              consolidate: true,
              consolidateAll: true,
              cleanDirectory: true,
              metadata: {
                  "Test Environment": "Stage",
                  "Browser": "Chrome  103.0.5060.53",
                  "Platform": "Windows 10",
                  "Executed": "Remote"
              }
          };
    
          reporter.generate(options);
          },
    
          afterLaunch: function afterLaunch() {
            var fs = require('fs');
            var output = '';
            fs.readdirSync('TestExecutionReport/').forEach(function (file) {
              if (!(fs.lstatSync('TestExecutionReport/' + file).isDirectory()))
                output = output + fs.readFileSync('TestExecutionReport/' + file);
            });
            fs.writeFileSync('TestExecutionReport/ConsolidatedReport.html', output, 'utf8');
        
          },
          plugins: [{
            package: require.resolve('protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin'),
            options: {
                automaticallyGenerateReport: true,
                removeExistingJsonReportFile: true,
                openReportInBrowser: true,
                pageTitle: "Project Report",
                pageFooter: "<div><p>Protractor with cucumber</p></div>",
                customData: {
                    title: 'Offer Creation UI test report',
                    data: [
                        { label: 'Project', value: 'Eternals UI Automation' },
                        { label: 'Created By', value: 'Drashti Gadhia' }
                    ]
                }
            },
    
        }]
      };
```